# TestFirst Performance Monitor Ruby

Tags: ruby

Im a newb trying to work some problems in this tutorial: http://testfirst.org/live/learn_ruby/performance_monitor

My current code passes 5 of 7, failing the last two. I think the problem is that I really don't get what its asking for:

```
it "returns the average time, not the total time, when running multiple times" do
  run_times = [8,6,5,7]
  fake_time = @eleven_am
  Time.stub(:now) { fake_time }
  average_time = measure(4) do
    fake_time += run_times.pop
  end
  average_time.should == 6.5
end
```

Here is what I currently have:

```
def measure(x=0)

  if x>0
    x.times do yield end
  else
    y= Time.now
    yield 
    elapsed_time=Time.now-y
    elapsed_time
  end
end
```

I'm not looking for a copy and paste answer. I am want to have clarity in what its asking for, and how I may tackle the challenge. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The spec is expecting that the performance monitor doesn't return the total of the times, but average. Your current version of the code is returning neither the total, nor the average, but the **count** of the times the `yield` statement was called.

Your current version of the solution is failing with the following error:

```
1) Performance Monitor returns the average time, not the total time, when running multiple times
   Failure/Error: average_time.should == 6.5
     expected: 6.5
          got: 4 (using ==)
   # ./06_performance_monitor/performance_monitor_spec.rb:64
```

So you are returning the **count** and not the **average** of `[8,6,5,7]`.

If the spec fails with the following error, it is returning the sum `( 26.0 = 8 + 6+ 5 + 7 )`:

```
1) Performance Monitor returns the average time, not the total time, when running multiple times
   Failure/Error: average_time.should == 6.5
     expected: 6.5
          got: 26.0 (using ==)
   # ./06_performance_monitor/performance_monitor_spec.rb:64
```

Couple of pointers to help you move forward:

1. Look at your assumption that the count should default to 0 (as defined by `x=0` param being passed to `measure`. If the program calls `measure` without any parameters, wouldn't it make sense to say it has been called once rather than zero times?
2. Try to understand why your program is returning `4` by walking through the code for `measure` on each value of [8,6,5,7], and by modifying/adding new test cases in `performance_monitor_spec.rb` file. **Hint:** The code isn't doing any performance monitoring in this path ;-)